# Dynamodb daily table dump of daily entries

Tags: database, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

What solution would you create if you need to export daily a table in dynamodb but not the whole content, just the entries from the day? Data pipeline would not work because it is exporting the whole table and I don't need that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a [CloudWatch Event](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html) to trigger a Lambda function and then run a query against your DynamoDB table to fetch data from the current day only.

Comment: How can you fetch data for this day only via query? If you make the timestamp hash key then you can only use equal, if you make it sort key then you have to provide a hashkey for the query. If you decide to go with scaning then when the table is big that will be very inefficient.

Comment: It's easy. Just create a Global Secondary Index on that field. You can see the docs here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SecondaryIndexes.html